Flutter share plus not working on Facebook
share_plus not working. It shows  post without any text but the example.com url exists in post only. it works with full text and url on Twitter, WhatsApp, gmail but not working for Facebook
What is the problem?
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com'); 

I made the configuration as same as documentation

You can pass a subject to the share method like is done in their docs:
 Share.share("https://google.com", subject: "Check out this url");

